# Labeling a a tikzpicture vertex in math mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I'm surprised I cannot find this answer on here yet; I want to label a vertex with math mode, no equals sign, and to clarify, this is not a node, but a vertex, perhaps rewriting a tikzpic might work but I'd rather know how to solve it this way.

Without trying to confuse anyway, I want to label my vertices with the labels under the curly braces; I replace vertices with one of the labels to illustrate that it does not work. The first example works, I am replacing node c with {$\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma+\delta+1}$}. The second one is what I want to work but does not (for reference, see my image, I am replacing vertex label c with {$\frac{\gamma+1}{gamma+delta+1}$}, or some variant of it).[image]

```
\newlength{\bulletwidth}\settowidth{\bulletwidth}{$\bullet$}
  \newcommand{\mitem}{\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}\hspace*{-\labelsep}\hspace*{-\bulletwidth}$\bullet$\hspace*{\labelsep}}
    \newcommand{\mend}{\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}}    
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{scrextend}%
 %   
 \usepackage{graphicx,tikz,tkz-berge,tkz-graph}
 \usetikzlibrary{trees,fit,shapes,arrows,calc, patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}%
  \usepackage{lipsum,soul}%soul is forstrike-through\st{}
  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,txfonts,soul,dsfont}
  \usepackage{yfonts,mathrsfs}
  \begin{document}
     \begin{center}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.25]
       \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]
          \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt}
            }       
 \tikzset{
     position label/.style={
        below = 15pt,
        text height = 1.5ex,
              text depth = 2ex
          },
          brace/.style={
       decoration={brace, mirror},
      decorate
    }
 }
          \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{d}
          \Vertex[x=1.5,y=0]{c}
          \Vertex[x=3,y=0]{b}
          \Vertex[x=4.5,y=0]{a}
          \Vertex[x=6,y=0]{p}

       \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={-,font=\scriptsize,above,sloped,midway}}
           \Edges[](d,c)
            \Edges[](c,b)%
            \Edges[](b,a)
            \Edges[](a,p)
     \draw [brace] (d.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$} (c.south);
        \draw [brace] (c.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}$} (b.south);
        \draw [brace] (a.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma+\delta+1}$} (p.south);
        \draw [brace] (b.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta})(\frac{1+\beta \frac{\gamma+1}{(\gamma+1)+\delta}}{1+\beta \frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}})$} (a.south);

        \end{tikzpicture}%
       \end{center}%
 \end{document}
```

The one below is the one I want to work:

```
 \newlength{\bulletwidth}\settowidth{\bulletwidth}{$\bullet$}
  \newcommand{\mitem}{\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftmargin}\hspace*{-\labelsep}\hspace*{-\bulletwidth}$\bullet$\hspace*{\labelsep}}
    \newcommand{\mend}{\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}}    
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{scrextend}%
 %   
 \usepackage{graphicx,tikz,tkz-berge,tkz-graph}
 \usetikzlibrary{trees,fit,shapes,arrows,calc, patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}%
  \usepackage{lipsum,soul}%soul is forstrike-through\st{}
  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,txfonts,soul,dsfont}
  \usepackage{yfonts,mathrsfs}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.25]
       \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
        \SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]
          \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt}
            }       
 \tikzset{
     position label/.style={
        below = 15pt,
        text height = 1.5ex,
              text depth = 2ex
          },
          brace/.style={
       decoration={brace, mirror},
      decorate
    }
 }
          \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{d}
          \Vertex[x=1.5,y=0]{{$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$}}
          \Vertex[x=3,y=0]{b}
          \Vertex[x=4.5,y=0]{a}
          \Vertex[x=6,y=0]{p}

       \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={-,font=\scriptsize,above,sloped,midway}}
           \Edges[](d,c)
            \Edges[]({$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$},b)%
            \Edges[](b,a)
            \Edges[](a,p)
     \draw [brace] (d.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$} ({$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$}.south);
        \draw [brace] ({$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$}.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}$} (b.south);
        \draw [brace] (a.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma+\delta+1}$} (p.south);
        \draw [brace] (b.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta})(\frac{1+\beta \frac{\gamma+1}{(\gamma+1)+\delta}}{1+\beta \frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}})$} (a.south);

        \end{tikzpicture}%
       \end{center}%
  \end{document}
```

Comment: If I add `\begin{document}` to the second example, I can compile it and get an output that looks reasonable. Could you perhaps add the missing `\begin{document}` and post an annotated screenshot from the output to indicate what you want to have changed? (And perhaps remove one "the curly braces" from "under the curly braces the curly braces" unless that is intended.)

Comment: @marmot, I fixed my mistakes, please try and compile it again, I forgot to implement the labeling change I asked about. You'll see it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I guess the culprit is `\Vertex[x=1.5,y=0]{{$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$}}` meaning that you can't give a mathematical expression to a vertex **name**.

Comment: Is there any way around this? I have the inkling that this should be do-able since this seems like a basic thing to want to do. You bolded `name', so I'm curious if you have a suspicion about getting around this?

Comment: I am not an expert on that package but from the error message it seems that this argument of the macro is taken to be the name of the vertex. E.g. `\path (0,0) node ($\frac{1}{2}$) {$\frac{1}{2}$};` does not work. Are there ways around it? I am pretty sure there are. Do you want a solution based on `tkz-berge,tkz-graph` or are you open to plain Ti*k*Z?

Comment: If you got a work-around, please post it. I still can't get a work-around like adding a plain number in front of it (e.g. 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here I post something that might go in the right direction. The reason why it took so long is that I had to drop so many packages that are not needed here. The issue is that you cannot use these mathematical expressions as node **names**, e.g. `\path (0,0) node ($\frac{1}{2}$) {$\frac{1}{2}$};` will fail. Of course, you can use those as node **contents**. This is the basis of the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-berge,tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.25]
 \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
 \SetUpVertex[Lpos=-90]
 \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=black, minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt}}       
 \tikzset{
     position label/.style={
        below = 15pt,
        text height = 1.5ex,
              text depth = 2ex
          },
          brace/.style={
       decoration={brace, mirror},
      decorate
    }
 }
 \node[VertexStyle] (d) at (0,0){};
 \node (c) at (1.5,0) {$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$};
 \node[VertexStyle] (b) at (3,0){};
 \node[VertexStyle] (a) at (4.5,0){};
 \node[VertexStyle] (p) at (6,0){};
 \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={-,font=\scriptsize,above,sloped,midway}}
 \Edges[](d,c)
 \Edges[](c,b)%
 \Edges[](b,a)
 \Edges[](a,p)
 \draw [brace] (d |- c.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta+1}$} (c.south);
 \draw [brace] (c.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}$} (b|- c.south);
 \draw [brace] (a|- c.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$\frac{\gamma+1}{\gamma+\delta+1}$} (p|- c.south);
 \draw [brace] (b|- c.south) -- node [position label, pos=0.5] {$(\frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta})(\frac{1+\beta \frac{\gamma+1}{(\gamma+1)+\delta}}{1+\beta \frac{\gamma}{\gamma+\delta}})$} (a|- c.south);
 \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}%
\end{document}
```

[image]